# How to add class with JS

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
let link = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-left p a");
for (var i =0;i<link.length;i++){
  link[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.classList.add('clicked')
  })
}
```

I click on a link and I add "clicked" class on `<a>` tag. My issue is: when I click on the next link I want to remove de previous class, but this now doesn't happen. How to do this? What changes should I add in my code for getting the result?

Answer (score 0):

Save a reference to the previously clicked element, and if it exists, remove the class:

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-left p a");
let lastLink;
for (let i = 0; i<links.length; i++){
  links[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (lastLink) {
      lastLink.classList.remove('clicked');
    }
    this.classList.add('clicked');
    lastLink = this;
  })
}
```

(note that because `links` is a *collection*, not a single element, it would probably make more sense to call it `links`, plural)

Answer (score 0):

```
let link = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-left p a");
for (var i =0;i<link.length;i++){
  link[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.target.classList.toggle('clicked')
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a functional approach to remove any elements with the clicked class before setting the next link to clicked.

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-left p a");

function clickedLinks() {
  return document.querySelectorAll(".clicked");
};
for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    clickedLinks().forEach(function(link) {
      link.classList.remove('clicked')
    });
    this.classList.add('clicked');
  })
}
```

Alternative using `forEach()` in place of the `for` loop and es6 arrow functions.

```
const rmClickedClass = () => (
  document.querySelectorAll(".clicked").forEach(
    (link) => link.classList.remove('clicked')
  )
);

document.querySelectorAll(".menu-left p a").forEach((link) => {
  link.addEventListener("click", () => {
    rmClickedClass();
    link.classList.add('clicked');
  });
};
```